# Using htmlextensions (html.HiddenFor) in own extention

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a HTML extension that combines three HiddenFor helpers.
I've managed to get as far as the below, which does at least compile:

```
 public static class BatchHelper {
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayHiddenSummary<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, BatchSummary batchSummary) where TModel : BatchSummary{

        var batchId = helper.HiddenFor(model => model.BatchId);
        var batchTotal = helper.HiddenFor(model => model.BatchTotal);
        var totalExpected = helper.HiddenFor(model => model.TotalExpected);

        var result = MvcHtmlString.Create(batchId.ToString() + batchTotal.ToString() + totalExpected.ToString());
        return result;
    }
}
```

I am having problems using this though, I am getting warnings that to parameters are required, which does make sense, though all the examples I've looked at seem to recognise it as an extension method and don't require the HtmlHelper parameter.

Thanks!

EDIT
The view code is as follows:

```
@using GridMvc.Html
@using GridMvc.Sorting
@using MyProj.Web.ViewModels.Receipt
@model MyProj.Web.ViewModels.Grids.DonorSummaryGrid

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@if (Model.BatchSummary != null) {
    // These Work fine, and are what I'm trying to put in the extension.
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BatchSummary.BatchId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BatchSummary.BatchTotal)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BatchSummary.TotalExpected)

    // this is where I want to use the extension
    @(Html.DisplayHiddenSummary(Model.BatchSummary))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should look as follows.  The TValue parameter is unnecessary.  Also, your lambdas were incorrect.

```
public static class BatchHelper {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayHiddenSummary<TModel,TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, TProperty batchSummary) 
where TModel : MyViewModel
where TProperty: BatchSummary

{

            var batchId = helper.HiddenFor(a => batchSummary.BatchId);
            var batchTotal = helper.HiddenFor(a => batchSummary.BatchTotal);
            var totalExpected = helper.HiddenFor(a => batchSummary.TotalExpected);

            var result = MvcHtmlString.Create(batchId.ToString() + batchTotal.ToString() + totalExpected.ToString());
            return result;
        } }
```

Your Razor should be as follows, assuming a strongly typed view of type MyViewModel and a property named BatchSummary:

```
@(Html.DisplayHiddenSummary<MyViewModel, BatchSummary>(Model.BatchSummary))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the 'Incorrect number of type parameters to method...' error.

Comment: That's interesting, as I posted this based on a clean implementation against a ViewModel I have in a currently running project which compiles and runs with no issues.  Would be interested to see the view that it's being called from. -- EDIT: What version of ASP.Net MVC is this referring to?

Comment: I've just added the View code, and realised I was logged on under a different user name, awaiting peer review or something. Anyway, MVC version is 5.2.3.0.

Comment: After picking it up again today, the incorrect number of params error has gone. However, the type BatchSummary is not the type of the view, it is contained within the ViewModel, which means I am getting an 'Cannot convert instance argument from System.Web.HtmlHelper<MyViewModel> to System.Web.HtmlHelper<BatchSummary>'

I have come up with a solution, which I'll post below, but it's a completely different approach. Would still like to see a solution to this though :)

Comment: Given the property of the Viewmodel that is of type BatchSummary, lets call it MyProperty: `@(Html.DisplayHiddenSummary<BatchSummary>(Model.MyProperty))`

Comment: Yup, tried that, thats what produces the error, a red squiggly line under the Html part. Tried running it anyway and it crashed out with
`Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MyProj.Web.ViewModels.Receipt.CreateReceiptSuccessfulViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayHiddenSummary' and the best extension method overload     'System.Web.Mvc.Html.BatchHelper.DisplayHiddenSummary<TModel>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, MyProj.Web.ViewModels.Receipt.BatchSummary)' has some invalid arguments
`

Comment: Edited post with solution given view of type MyViewModel referencing property called BatchSummary.

Comment: Brilliant! Works a treat. Thanks for your help - and persistance; I think I learned quite a lot from this :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably are not calling it correctly. You are making it generic but you have BatchSummary hard coded. So... the generic part is unnecessary (though you could use it or pass in an expression similar to other helpers). For this, you could simplify it down to:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString DisplayHiddenSummary(this HtmlHelper helper, BatchSummary batchSummary)
 {
    var batchId = helper.HiddenFor(model => model.BatchId);
    var batchTotal = helper.HiddenFor(model => model.BatchTotal);
    var totalExpected = helper.HiddenFor(model => model.TotalExpected);

    var result = MvcHtmlString.Create(batchId.ToString() + batchTotal.ToString() + totalExpected.ToString());
    return result;
}
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayHiddenSummary(Model.BatchSummary)
```

You may have to add the namespace of this helper using an @using directive, adding it to the web.config, or by just throwing this into System.Web.Mvc.Html.

You might also consider Display and Editor templates instead of this custom helper.

Comment: Doesn't work, I get a System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'HiddenFor' and no extension method 'HiddenFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: You have to add the correct namespaces. Try adding `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html`. See my 2nd to last sentence in my answer

Comment: Put in the namespaces in both the View and class, still no go.

Comment: If you are getting the errors within the View, you have to close and re-open them in Visual Studio in order for it to update... usually when you change or add namespaces or change models

Comment: Well, I came back and reopened VS and the 'does not contain a definition' problem had gone. Unfortunately the code didn't work, but thanks for that hint, I shall remember that next time!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually got something working. Had a rumage in the MVC source code and found a snippet which helped me come up with the following:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using StJudes_Donor.Web.ViewModels.Receipt;

namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html {
public static class BatchHelper {

    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayHiddenSummary(this HtmlHelper helper, BatchSummary batchSummary) {
        StringBuilder batchId = HiddenBuilder(batchSummary.BatchId.ToString(), "BatchId");
        StringBuilder batchTotal = HiddenBuilder(batchSummary.BatchTotal.ToString(), "BatchTotal");
        StringBuilder batchExpected = HiddenBuilder(batchSummary.TotalExpected.ToString(), "BatchExpected");

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(batchId.ToString() + batchTotal.ToString() + batchExpected.ToString());
    }

    private static StringBuilder HiddenBuilder(String value, String id) {
        StringBuilder inputItemBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        TagBuilder hiddenInput = new TagBuilder("input");
        hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("type", HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(InputType.Hidden));
        hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("name", id);
        hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("value", value);
        inputItemBuilder.Append(hiddenInput.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));

        return inputItemBuilder;
    }
}
}
```

It is called in the View  with

```
 @Html.DisplayHiddenSummary(Model.BatchSummary)
```

this produced the following HTML

```
<input id="BatchId" name="BatchId" type="hidden" value="1">
<input id="BatchTotal" name="BatchTotal" type="hidden" value="21.31">
<input id="BatchExpected" name="BatchExpected" type="hidden" value="12.31">
```